# How to compare Array index according to button tag?

Tags: iphone

```
indexpath.row for array                          b.tag

0 Date1                                          0
1 india                                          1
2 pakistan                                       2
3 Date2                                          3
4 Zimbabwe                                       3
5 England                                        4
6 Date3                                          6
7 Australia                                      5
8 Westindes                                      6
9 Date3                                          9
10 Shrilanka                                     7
11 southAfrica                                   8
```

Here, indexpath.row for array is my Array. Now when i click on `b.tag=3` then I want to display Array index 4th value i.e Zimbabwe and not the Date2 which is on array index 3. Similarly, for b.tag=6 and b.tag=9. For that following is the code that i have written.

please take a look...

```
if (b.tag!=[arr objectAtIndex:path])
{
   NSLog(@"Team name %@",[arr objectAtIndex:b.tag]);
}
```

From the above code my first record result is coming right i.e of b.tag=1 and b.tag=2,but not for others because my Array index and b.tag are different. So please help me out of this.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not change the contents of the array to better reflect your button tags?

It seems you have two different data types represented by one array, split them out:

```
NSArray *teamArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"India", @"Pakistan", @"Zimbabwe", @"England", @"Australia", @"WestIndies", @"Shrilanka", @"SouthAfrica", nil];

NSLog(@"Team name %@",[teamArray objectAtIndex:b.tag]);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have passed a same tag for two instance of buttons why don't you just set the tag like this `b.tag = indexPath.row?`.

**UPDATE**

use this code -

```
NSInteger index = b.tag;
if(b.tag != 0 && b.tag %3 == 0){
    index = index+1;
}

 NSLog(@"Team name %@",[arr objectAtIndex:index]);
```

**Update**

I have tested this code and it's showing index = 4 when index was 4 it's not increasing the index value

```
self.view.tag = 4;
NSInteger index = self.view.tag;

if(index%3 == 0 && index != 0)
{
    index = index+1;
    NSLog(@"Index Value Is %d",index);
}
NSLog(@"Index Value Is %d",index);
```

Comment: i don't have to display anything on b.tag=0/3/6/9.And i want to set b.tag for team like the above image.It's the requirement of project.

Comment: @Rahul.. thanx for reply but consider in i m selecting b.tag=4 then this logic is wrong..

Comment: @Vishakha no this logic is correct when you select 4 then 3%4 will not be 0 so therefor the index will be passed as 4 and you will England as value.

Comment: @Rahul yes u r logic is write but if  b.tag=4 then  control comes to the if condition & index is 4 b'cos index=b.tag so index=4+1 means index=5 ok.. but in my program index=4 button when it comes in condition index=4+1 and out put index=4 how it is possible

Comment: @Rahul ok i ll check it and let u know

Comment: @Rahul yes made changes as per ur code but same problem index is not increment.even it is not increment with any b.tag only for record one means b.tag=1 and b.tag=2 it gives proper output but not for others

Comment: don't check with b.tag check with index as per the newer code it seems to be working fine. Or you can separate your dates from the array to another array as hundreth suggests.